# Change springs behavior on NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, mockito, ioc-container

In integration tests with spring application context I write quite often something like this in my configuration classes

```
@Bean
public MyComponent myComponent() {
   return mock(MyComponent.class);
}
```

Sometimes I have to create those beans just to fulfill dependency requirements, sometimes I wire those mocks in my test to configure them.

In any case I'd love to get rid off those bean definitions. Is there a way to tell spring to create a mock of a type it is missing instead of throwing `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`?

Comment: If you don't need the dependency, why do you have it? If you do need it, then what do you test in your integration tests?

Comment: What kind of an integration test it is if you have to mock dependencies "quite often" ? It is a smell that is maybe showing you that design of the application is a bit off. Integration test should mock as few things as possible.

Comment: Call it a service test, a component test or whatever you want. I mock (mostly) everything not tightly coupled to the service I'm testing and everything making requests outside the application (DB-Repositories, WS-Services, ...). Sometimes I wire beans from that I don't use all the features and so I don't need a full wiring for them. That all leads to the above described situation without having (more than normal) code smells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [spring-auto-mock](https://github.com/rinoto/spring-auto-mock).

By registering the [AutoMockRegistryPostProcessor](https://github.com/rinoto/spring-auto-mock/blob/master/src/main/java/sbg/rinoto/spring/mock/AutoMockRegistryPostProcessor.java) all the dependencies that Spring cannot find will be automagically converted to mockito mocks.

Here you have a [test example](https://github.com/rinoto/spring-auto-mock/blob/master/src/test/java/sbg/rinoto/spring/mock/AutoMockRegistryProcessorTest.java).